# How to create a signature for bingx api in node js

Tags: node.js, hmacsha256

I want to generate a signature for Bingx website Api

Here's my code:

```
const Base64 = require('crypto-js/enc-base64');
const hmacSHA256  = require('crypto-js/hmac-sha256');

let originString = 'POST/api/v1/user/getBalanceapiKey=my_api_key' + '&currency=USDT&timestamp=' + Date.now();
let signature = hmacSHA256(originString, my_secret_key);
signature = Base64.stringify(signature);
signature = encodeURIComponent(signature);
```

I send the signature to the api But I get this error "signature not match"

Here's the bingx api authentication documentation:
[link1](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/swap/authentication.html#signature) and
[link2](https://github.com/BingX-API/BingX-swap-api-doc/blob/master/Perpetual_Swap_API_Documentation.md)

Comment: The origin string that you are generating for the signature is not formatted correctly. The string should be in the format of [HTTP method] + [URL] + [param1=value1] + [param2=value2] + ... and the params should be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @Silentobserver I Check again, the origin string is formatted as the same as you wrote. Could you modify the origin string and send it please?